# How do I scrape google readers with mechanize (using cookies)

Tags: ruby, cookies, mechanize, web-scraping

I'm trying scrape google readers but I've got problems...I wish to log in google readers and get a valid cookie...then try  enter in this page:

```
'http://www.google.es/reader/atom/user/-/state/com.google/reading-list'
```

if my cookies work and I'm logged in I only need to put `"user/-/"` and it will enter inside my google reader's XML version....

It's in theory ... I log in inside google readers and it redirects ... then I copy my SID .... and I create a manual cookie using this and the google reader's API info

```
http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI

name SID
domain .google.com
path /
expires 1600000000
```

with my cookie create I try enter inside:

```
'http://www.google.es/reader/atom/user/-/state/com.google/reading-list'
```

but it don't work .... I think I'm creating my cookie in a bad way but I read the API about `CookieJar` and `Mechanize::Cookie`, but I don't find any example about how to use it ... I've tried in different ways but none work ... please someone can help me about how use this cookie....

Comment: Can you give some more information what you mean when you say "it don't work"? What errors or exceptions do you see? Can you show some code samples?

Comment: what I can suggest in general is to first deal with authentication, which you've glossed over here.  For example, an sid and token are required as per the google reader docs.  also, as the Tin Man suggests, actual code and result are required to troubleshoot.  (Remove your password, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

We do all our web scraping with iMacros (partly free/open source, partly commercial). That works well. No matter what you use, you need something that automates a **real** web browser. Other options are Selenium or Watir, although these are more geared towards web testing.